# Javascript - Too much recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

So, I'm making a function which solves a 4x4 sudoku. It takes in a 2D array and all the empty fields are replaced with 0s. With the isSafe function I'm trying to split the checks into multiple functions that way that it's easier to read. Althought I've tried some forms of avoiding the too much recursion as to implement a certant amount of checks etc.

I've tried setting maxIterations, tried returning false, returning null... Really was out of ideas.

I've noticed that it crashes quite fast, It can only solve a few numbers and then the error occurs. If anyone has a more efficent way please comment.

```js
function solverFor4x4(grid) {
    let number = generateRandom(1, 5, [0, 5]);
    if (!number) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(number)
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            if(grid[i][j] == 0 && isSafe(grid, number, i, j)) {
                grid[i][j] = number;
            }
        }
    }
    showSolution(grid);
}

function isSafe(grid, number, i, j) {
    if(isSafeRow(grid, number, i, j) && isSafeColumn(grid, number, i, j) && isSafeArea(grid, number, i, j)) {
        return true;
    }
}

function isSafeRow(grid, number, i, j) {
    if (grid[i].includes(number)) {
        solverFor4x4(grid);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


function isSafeColumn(grid, number, i, j) {
    let array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        if(grid[i][j] == number) {
            solverFor4x4(grid);
        } else {
            array.push(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }

    if(array.includes(number)) {
        solverFor4x4(grid);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function isSafeArea(grid, number, i, j) {
    return true;
}

function generateRandom(min, max, exclude) {
    let random;
    let counter = 0;
    const maxIterations = 100;
    while (!random && counter < maxIterations) {
        const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        if (exclude.indexOf(x) === -1) {
            random = x;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return random || null;
}
```

EDIT: Forgot to place the code, sorry.

Comment: Actually, there's really only one: you have a function that is calling itself (either directly or indirectly) that's causing a loop (intentionally or unintentionally), but you didn't provide an exit path for the loop, so it just keeps calling itself until you run out of stack space to hold the unresolved function calls.

Comment: The remedy is to either provide the recursive function with an exit condition so that it can return, or stop calling the function from its own function body.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So, in the code I'm mainly returning true's. If I understood you correctly should I try to implement a bit of returning false? English isn't my first language.

Comment: what does `isSafeArea`?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze It's a function that isn't finished yet, but It's going to grab some arrays from the 2D array and check if they contain something. I've tried removing it temp. but same result

Comment: do you have some examples and wanted results?

Comment: @NinaScholz Well yes. A example input would be: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 4, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0]].

Comment: what is `generateRandom` doing?

Comment: @NinaScholz I've updated the code to include that function aswell. Generate random generates a random number between 1 to 5 excluding 0 and 5.

Comment: a main problem could be the assignment of a value whichlooks at first right, but later it does not lead to a result. you need in this case a backtracking or take a copy of the grid and go another path, if the result does not fit. another hint is to use a shorter function for random value, like `function generateRandom(min, max) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; }`. for 1 ... 4 call `generateRandom(1, 4)`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Would that new code for the generateRandom function provide a 0? Also, I didn’t really understand your explanation. Do you think the problem is the in the generateRandom or in the way I’m searching for a number that passes all my isSafe checks?

Comment: actually i do not understand, what you are doing despite of assigning values, if they fit. this may not give a wanted result and never ends the recursion. to overcome this, you could take a copy of grid with the new inserted number. if this do not lead to a result, remove this last value and try a different value.

Comment: @NinaScholz So, the solverFor4x4 generates a random number, loops thru the grid(2D array) and check if the number is equal to zero(needs replacement, and check is it safe to place the number there. “Safe” meaning that the same number isn’t in the same column, row and 2x2 area. I’ve split the isSafe function into multiple for ease of writing and understanding. isSafeRow takes the i where the solverFor4x4 stopped on the number and checks that row. isSafeColumn tries to increment i(rows), but checking the same column(j). And both of those if fail just call solverFor4x4 again. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here's the updated code:

```
function solverFor4x4(grid) {
    let number = generateRandom(1, 5, [0, 5]);
    if (!number) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(number)
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            if(grid[i][j] == 0 && isSafe(grid, number, i, j)) {
                grid[i][j] = number;
            }
        }
    }
    showSolution(grid);
}

function isSafe(grid, number, i, j) {
    if(isSafeRow(grid, number, i, j) && isSafeColumn(grid, number, i, j) && isSafeArea(grid, number, i, j)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function isSafeRow(grid, number, i, j) {
    if (grid[i].includes(number)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


function isSafeColumn(grid, number, i, j) {
    let array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        if(grid[i][j] == number) {
            return false;
        } else {
            array.push(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }

    if(array.includes(number)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function isSafeArea(grid, number, i, j) {
    return true;
}

function generateRandom(min, max, exclude) {
    let random;
    let counter = 0;
    const maxIterations = 100;
    while (!random && counter < maxIterations) {
        const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        if (exclude.indexOf(x) === -1) {
            random = x;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return random || null;
}
```

If not working try this:

```
function solverFor4x4(grid) {
    let number = generateRandom(1, 5, [0, 5]);
    if (!number) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(number)
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            if(grid[i][j] == 0 && isSafe(grid, number, i, j)) {
                grid[i][j] = number;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    showSolution(grid);
}

function isSafe(grid, number, i, j) {
    if(isSafeRow(grid, number, i, j) && isSafeColumn(grid, number, i, j) && isSafeArea(grid, number, i, j)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function isSafeRow(grid, number, i, j) {
    return !grid[i].includes(number);
}

function isSafeColumn(grid, number, i, j) {
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        if(grid[i][j] == number) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function isSafeArea(grid, number, i, j) {
    return true;
}

function generateRandom(min, max, exclude) {
    let random;
    let counter = 0;
    const maxIterations = 100;
    while (!random && counter < maxIterations) {
        const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        if (exclude.indexOf(x) === -1) {
            random = x;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return random || null;
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot too add some sort of recursion into your updated code? Because that doesn't change the grid at all. Could you add a little clarification, Thanks

Comment: can you show me the specific error you have?

Comment: Well the grid just returns as unchanged?

Comment: I have added another code. Try it

Comment: The difference between these two code blocks is that the first one continues to loop through the grid even after it finds a zero and assigns a number to it, whereas the second one breaks out of the inner loop after it finds a zero and assigns a number to it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue with the code is that it does not update the grid with the number placed if all checks return true. Also, the "isSafe" function does not return false if one of the checks fail. Try modifying the code as follows:

```
function solverFor4x4(grid) {
    let number = generateRandom(1, 5, [0, 5]);
    if (!number) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(number)
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            if(grid[i][j] == 0 && isSafe(grid, number, i, j)) {
                grid[i][j] = number;
                solverFor4x4(grid);
            }
        }
    }
    showSolution(grid);
}

function isSafe(grid, number, i, j) {
    if(isSafeRow(grid, number, i, j) && isSafeColumn(grid, number, i, j) && isSafeArea(grid, number, i, j)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function isSafeRow(grid, number, i, j) {
    if (grid[i].includes(number)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


function isSafeColumn(grid, number, i, j) {
    let array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        if(grid[i][j] == number) {
            return false;
        } else {
            array.push(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }

    if(array.includes(number)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This should solve the problem, but keep in mind that the function may still not work correctly due to the random number generation approach.